# Why does async code mess up my dataloader in a graphql resolver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, dataloader

I have a dataloader that I'm using to batch requests to a service to get my user's addresses.
The loader doesn't batch requests correctly when the parent resolver uses async code.
Here's a general idea of what my code looks like:

```
// User.ts 
import Demographic from './Demographic'

export type User { 
 name: 'User', 
 description: 'User',
 ...
 fields: () => {
  someField: ...
  demographicInformation: {
     type: Demographic,
     resolve: async (source, args, context) => {
      // removing the following line causes the loader in Demographics.ts to batch properly
      const [hasViewPermissions, hasAuthForDemographics] = await Promise.all([getViewPermissions(), getAuthForDemographics()])
      if (hasAuth && hasAuthForDemographics){ return source}
      else { return null } 
     
     }

 } 

}
...
```

```
//Demographics.ts
export type Demographics { 
 name: 'somename', 
 description: '',
 fields: {
    name: // ...
    address: {
     type: Address, 
     resolve:  async (source, args, context) => {
       return myloaders.addressloader.load(myid)
     }

   }
}
```

I'm aware that the [dataloader docs](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader#batching) say that  "DataLoader will coalesce all individual loads which occur within a single frame of execution (a single tick of the event loop)", however I don't fully understand why using an async/await messes that up if that's done in the parent resolver (User in my case).
And, I need to have the parent check the auth using some form of async code, is there a way to still make these auth calls at the parent level and also use the dataloader effectively?

I've seen [this issue noted](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader/issues/150) in Github as well, but I don't think any workaround (such as adding the async calls to the loader) will work for me.

Comment: since `resolve: (source, args, context) => {` is not `async` you will get an error trying to use `await`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry this was just some pseudo-code, let me fix that. My actual code does not get an error - but the loader doesnt batch

Comment: Use a dataloader for `getViewPermissions()` and `getAuthForDemographics()` as well. Otherwise every `Demographics` object will resolve on its own (after waiting for its individual permissions & auth), and the dataloader is not able to batch the address loading because each `.address` resolution happens separately.